# Java Mongo - findAndReplace returns document dates in subkeys

Tags: java, mongodb, cfml

I have a slight problem with return data from Mongo find() **vs** a findOneAndReplace().

First, to know I'm working on an API that queries Mongo and returns data in JSON format.

Problem I'm having is that if I do a findOneAndReplace() to update and return the modified document, much like so:

```java
// javaDocument() is just a org.bson.Document
var modDoc = jobsCollection.findOneAndReplace( javaDocument({"_id": jobid}), javaDocument(jobData), foarOptions );

if(isDefined("modDoc")) {
  sReturn.DATA = deserializeJSON(modDoc.toJSON());
}
```

the dates set in my document returns within subkeys named "$date", which I do not want:

[image]

It really should read:
`"created_at": "2022-02-03T10:15:01.634Z"`

Doing a simple `jobsCollection.find()` however, seems to return me the date appropriately, like so:

```java
var data= [];
jobsCollection.find( javaDocument({}) ).into(data);
sReturn.DATA = data;
```

[image]

What am I missing here ? I could simple copy the "$date" key and fix the structure, but I don't always know where in the structure I'll have dates.... Is there a way I could have this properly returned with FindOneAndReplace() ? I'm thinking in might have something to do with the `modDoc.toJSON()` but haven't quite found my answer yet...

Thanks for your time. Cheers! Pat

Comment: `"created_at":  { $date: "2022-02-03T10:15:01.634Z" }` is just a representation of the date type data as JSON; see [MongoDB Extended JSON v2](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/). You can query the data from a tool like mongo shell or Compass and verify.

Comment: Yeah, the date {"$date": "..." } IS valid and I know mongosh / compass shows it properly. The problem I have is I'm returning the full document in a JSON response... When I call my findDocByID() function, I'll receive a JSON struct with dates {"created": "full date string"}, which is fine cause I can parse it properly with CFML ParseDateTime(), but issue I have is that the actual date string in case of a "findOneAndReplace()" function (for my replaceDoc()) isn't returned the same way. I'd like for both to be returned the same way (with or without the "$date). Thx!